# Regex: how to match between a URL and something else?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, text

I dug up a regular expression that does the trick when it comes to identifying URLs. Here it is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

What i need to do next is to match everything between a URL that is identified and some other character, preferable a newline character.

> So if I had a block of text like this... that ended with a url, like
>   it's about to, I want the entire block of text gone.
>   http://checkoutmysite.com.

should turn to nothing since the regex will match everything backwards to the nearest newline and then take it all out.

I've tried a thing or two and can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use verbatim strings `@"Regexstring"`, advantage is, you don't need to double escape. So e.g. `Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+");` is fine.
2. Most characters inside a character class don't need to be escaped.

   ```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"http://([\w+?.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\/?.:;',]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   ```

   Should be the same than yours.
3. If you want to remove something before your regex till the line break before, put a `.*` before and brackets around your pattern, then replace with `$1`

   ```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@".*(http://([\w+?.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()_\-=+\\/?.:;',]*)?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   ```

   then `regex.replace` with `$1` as replace string.

Comment: I put on a [answer on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/108141) some resources that where useful to me.